# RESTful way to route employees workhours by month

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

i'm wondering what route to choose.

I got a view containing employees workhours, and the route file looks like this:

```
resources :employees do
    resources :workhours do
end
```

so the url is:

```
/users/:user_id/workhours/:id
```

What i want to do is only showing monthly hours with links to next and prev month.
What is the most RESTful way to do this? I have read that you shouldn't nest the url to deep, but i don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the resource workhour contain? It is the daily workhours for an employee?

Comment: yes, that is correct. right now the url when showing for each month like this: /users/2/workdays?date=2013-02-18. Not that pretty..

Comment: If you want your workhours id to be a month-and-year id, you can do that using to_param method. Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast